# Prevent namespaces of top Config from getting wiped out when loading and configuring other .config in Unity

Tags: c#, configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

This is somewhat specific and difficult situation to explain, so bear with me.

I have created a UnityContainerExtension that is responsible for loading and configuring other .config files.

For example, my App.Config file looks like this:

```
  <configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>

    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

        <assembly name="SomeAssembly" />
        <namespace name="SomeAssembly.SomeNameSpace" />

        <container>

            <extension type="ConfigSectionExtension" />
            <extension type="TestExtension" />

        </container>

    </unity>

  </configuration>
```

My first extension `ConfigSectionExtension` runs code (following) that loads in and configures the container with another .config file. ex.

```
    var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "logging.config"};
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration( fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None );
    ((UnityConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection( "unity" )).Configure( Container );
```

This code runs fine, however the TestExtension extension in my config cannot be resolved after the Container has been configured with the `logging.config` file.

The specific response is

```
    "The type name or alias TestExtension could not be resolved."
```

If I remove the code that loads and configures the `logging.config` file with the container, then both extensions are found. Is there any way to make this work?

This is essentially my approach to the problem of not being able to link together multiple .config files. If someone knows a better way to link .config files together for Unity, I would of course be open to that solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have an OK solution. For my extension I can just fully qualify the Type and it will work. ie.

```
    <extension type="MediaInjectorUI.ContainerExtensions.ConfigSectionExtension, MediaInjectorUI" />
    <extension type="MediaInjectorUI.ContainerExtensions.TestExtension, MediaInjectorUI" />
```

Maybe not the prettiest thing in the world, but itdoes the job.